# Touchscreen sensibility under Ubuntu

Tags: touchscreen

So, a friend bequeathed me with a Touchscreen All-In-One computer. Model HP Touchsmart 610. I did the only thing a good person would do, I installed Ubuntu (now Ubuntu 19.04).

I live in an area where at night ants with wings (don't ask) come and fly against the screen (because it's the only light source in my geek's den, don't tell).

What happens is that they activate the keyboard, click links, basically make working impossible for some time. Now... they are not that big. And still, advertisers think I am interested in their blinking products. Because the ants are.

Is there any way to set the sensibility of the screen in Ubuntu? I just installed the Ubuntu, no special drivers (sound is not working but that is a story for a later post) and the screen works out of the box. There is nothing that points to configuration for a touchscreen in my screen management in settings.

I am not really using the touch component of the screen, so disabling it fully would help too. But I think there should be some way to set the sensitivity to "poke it really hard to register a touch event".